# Google map showing only some markers but all markers shown in debug mode

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

A few of my markers are not showing in the map I created and I have drilled down the reason being too many API calls. But the problem is that even after adding setTimout/ delay code all markers are not shown. When i debug the code in chrome though it works fine (even when i remove all the break points and allow the website to load - all markers are loaded without any issues)

[www.khojiye.com](http://www.khojiye.com) is the link

```
function map_marker(ajax_result,address_length)
{

    val =   ajax_result[counter];
    if($.trim(val)!=""){
        //alert(i);
        //alert(val);
        var valA    =   val.split('@@@');

        setTimeout(geocoder.geocode( { 'address': valA[0]}, function(results, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                // Set the coordonates of the new point
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                //bounds.extend(latLng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                {
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: valA[0],
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon:valA[1]
                });

                // The HTML that is shown in the window of each item (when the icon it's clicked)
                var html = "<div style='width:150px; margin-top: -12px;'><h3 style='font-size:16px; font-weight:500;'>"+valA[2]+"</h3><h4 style='font-size:15px; line-height:21px;'>"+valA[0]+"</h4><a href='"+valA[3]+"'>View Detail</h4></div>";

                // Binds the infoWindow to the point
                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                // Add the marker to the array
                markers.push(marker);
                counter++;  
                a_c++;
                if(counter<address_length)
                    map_marker(ajax_result,address_length);

            }
            else{

                //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                //marker = '';
                //markers.push(marker); 
                //console.log(status);
                counter++;  
                b_c++;
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){

                counter--;
                console.log(counter);
                delay=delay*5;
                }

                if(counter<address_length)
                    map_marker(ajax_result,address_length);

            }
        }),delay);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what i did is a hack or not: 
1. it seems my use of set timeout was incorrect
2. I removed the setTimeout from top function and added it as
 `setTimeout(function() {map_marker(ajax_result,address_length);},delay);}`